# How can 坚强 be used after 选择 in this term "选择坚强和希望"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I recently came across this term **"选择坚强和希望"** and I wonder how 坚强 is used here. In every single dictionary I have searched 坚强 is an adjective, so how can an adjective be used after 选择 (to choose)? And alongside 希望 (hope) as a noun? This term is loosely translated to "to choose strength and hope" in English but because 坚强 is an adjective, I do not get the grammar behind this. If anyone can be kind enough to explain, I thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: 坚强 - strong(adj), staunch(adj), or doughtiness(n).

Answer (score 0):

It can be used after 选择 because it's a noun.

Words don't necessarily have a fixed designation as nouns or adjectives. This isn't unique to Chinese, other languages have this feature. Maybe it's more pronounced in Chinese because words don't change according to grammatical usage.

I don't think there is anything loose about the translation, it seems pretty accurate to me:

```
Choose strength and hope.
```

Also, here *hope* is being used as a noun (in both the English translation and the original Chinese), but you could say 我希望见到她 (I hope to see her) and 她给我希望  (She gives me hope). In both languages, the word can be a noun or a verb, and the only indication is its position in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

What about 'strong' and 'weak' in English? Are they definitely adjectives?

The strong survive, the weak go under.
强者生存下去，弱者灭亡。

面对死亡，陈琳琼选择了坚强和希望。
Confronting (imminent) death, Chen Linqiong chose strength and hope.

Answer (score 0):

There are neither strict rules for word types nor for word usages of grammar of the Chinese language. For example, when talking about the apples, you can say, “红的苹果比较甜”, or “红的比较甜”.

In English, you must use “the”, such as “the red are sweeter”.

In Chinese, you can say “这个红的比较甜”. But “这个” is not necessary.